# ¿Como mostrar datos que no se muestran en mi union de dos tablas sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una petición para unir dos tablas en sql server, lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[Venta] as V
JOIN [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[VentaD] as VD on V.ID = VD.ID
WHERE V.FechaEmision between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-30'
ORDER BY V.MovID
```

En esta petición me salen 5000 registros, pero cuando hago esta otra:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[Venta] as V
JOIN [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[VentaD] as VD on V.ID = VD.ID
JOIN CB on CB.Codigo = VD.Articulo
WHERE V.FechaEmision between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-30'
ORDER BY V.MovID
```

Me salen 4200 registros, me salen menos que en la de arriba, ¿Como le puedo hacer para poder ver los 800 registros que no se estan mostrando cuando hago el otro join? Espero me puedan apoyar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que usar el operador `EXCEPT`. Aunque

```
SELECT V.*, VD.*
FROM [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[Venta] as V
JOIN [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[VentaD] as VD on V.ID = VD.ID
WHERE V.FechaEmision between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-30'
EXCEPT
SELECT V.*, VD.*
FROM [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[Venta] as V
JOIN [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[VentaD] as VD on V.ID = VD.ID
JOIN CB on CB.Codigo = VD.Articulo
WHERE V.FechaEmision between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-30'
```

Aunque otra opción es usar `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[Venta] as V
JOIN [172.35.65.212].[IBCO].[dbo].[VentaD] as VD on V.ID = VD.ID
WHERE V.FechaEmision between '2023-04-01' and '2023-04-30'
AND   NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM CB WHERE CB.Codigo = VD.Articulo)
ORDER BY V.MovID
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, utilicé las dos y me sirvieron al 100.